# Does R allows operators to be compound expressions?

Tags: r, functional-programming

In Harold Abelson's "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs", which uses the `Lisp` programming language, one of the exercises asks you to evaluate the following code:

```
(define (a-plus-abs-b a b)
((if (> b 0) + -) a b))
```

One way to do this in `R` is of course:

```
APlusAbsB <- function(a, b){
  if(b > 0) a + b else a - b
}
```

Then I am repeating the `a`s and `b`s.

My question is: does `R` allow operators to be compound expressions (e.g., `if (> b 0) + -)`)? For example, is there a way to do something like

```
APlusAbsB <- function(a, b){  ## this doesn't work
  if(b > 0) "+" else "-" (a, b)    ## gives "+" or "-"
}
```

Comment: the update is very nice, but you should probably post it as an answer rather than as part of the question ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
APlusAbsB <- function(a, b){
  (if(b > 0) `+` else `-`)(a, b)
}
```

Here the `if` will return a function and then you call it with the parenthesis syntax. For example

```
APlusAbsB(1,5)
# [1] 6
APlusAbsB(1,-1)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: This variation also works: `a_plus_abs_b <- function(a, b) 'if'('>'(b, 0), '+', '-')(a, b)` except replace the single quotes with backticks - SO's markdown interprets backticks as special.

Comment: `you can \` escape backticks \` just like special characters in \r`... `a_plus_abs_b <- function(a, b) \`if\`(\`>\`(b, 0), \`+\`, \`-\`)(a, b)`

Comment: The problem with doing it that way is that the `APlusAbsB` function isn't vectorised (feed it a vector of `a` or `b` and get an error). The vectorised version is harder to write because R doesn't support applying a vector of functions over vectors of parameters without looping. The natural R approach is to use `ifelse`. I'll not put an answer in because the Q was about the principle, and not the practice!

Comment: @Spacedman I did try to use `ifelse` but couldn't get it to work. Could you put an answer?

Comment: @MasatoNakazawa Did you try `APlusAbsB <- function(a, b) { ifelse(b > 0, \`+\`, \`-\`)(a, b) }`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to brilliant programmers I have three alternatives. I ran a benchmark test and Alternatives 1 and 2 are almost exactly the same and faster than the Alternative 3 that uses `ifelse`.

```
APlusAbsB1 <- function(a, b){(if(b > 0) `+` else `-`)(a, b)}
APlusAbsB2 <- function(a, b) {`if`(`>`(b, 0), `+`, `-`)(a, b)}
APlusAbsB3 <- function(a, b) { ifelse(b > 0, `+`, `-`)(a, b)}

microbenchmark(APlusAbsB1(sample(10, 1), sample(-10:10, 1)),
               APlusAbsB2(sample(10, 1), sample(-10:10, 1)),
               APlusAbsB3(sample(10, 1), sample(-10:10, 1)), times=10000)
Unit: microseconds
                                         expr   min    lq median    uq     max neval
 APlusAbsB1(sample(10, 1), sample(-10:10, 1)) 3.925 4.529  4.831 5.133 912.546 10000
 APlusAbsB2(sample(10, 1), sample(-10:10, 1)) 3.925 4.529  4.830 5.132 854.587 10000
 APlusAbsB3(sample(10, 1), sample(-10:10, 1)) 4.831 5.736  5.737 6.340 851.568 10000
```